# IOSDriver() is not working. Instead it is opening remote session, when I using RemoteWebDriver() that time my test cases are passing

Tags: java, selenium, appium

Hi can anyone help me why this is happening i have no idea, for my appium mobile test scripts for MAC iPad app, when I i use IOSDriver() it is not working giving me multiple errors such as randomly, sometimes session cannot b created, or no element found, etc., and the same code when I run with RemoteWebDriver() it is working fine and executing all my test cases.

Comment: can you show us your code?

Comment: Cross check the binary version compatibility.